# How to start a Mysql server in Java programatically?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

My Java application needs to connect to a Mysql database file which is present on disk.

For that, it needs to start a Mysql server and use the server to read the file. The problem is that I am not sure how to start the server from within my Java code, read the Mysql file, make modifications to it, and then stop the server.

Currently, I am using something like below, but I don't see a way to start the server from code.

```
MysqlDataSource dataSource = new MysqlDataSource();
dataSource.setUser("root");
dataSource.setPassword("root");
dataSource.setServerName("MysqlServer");
Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
```

Using this, I run into

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

which I think is because the server is not up. How do I start the server from code?

Comment: Were you able to run the app if mysql is started manually?  Network errors could come from antivirus software/firewall etc

Comment: @yan: yes, the app works if mysql server is running.

Comment: @Sai: I am using OSX but looking for a platform independent solution.

Comment: If you want platform independence then why not use Apache Derby instead of MySQL?

Answer (score 4):

- Option 1 :  Find out how to start mysql from command line. Then use [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to do that
- Option 2:  Use embeddable version of mysql 
  , if that suits  you :  See [details](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-mxj/en/connector-mxj-configuration-java-object.html)

Answer (score 4):

you need to run 'mysqld.exe' to start the mysql server. This file can be found in the 'bin' folder in the mysql main folder (Assuming that you are working in windows). In my case 'mysql-5.6.10-win32\bin\mysqld.exe' .

From Java if you want to do the same - I used the following code and it worked. Hope it helps.

======================================================

```
String command = "~path~\\mysql-5.6.10-win32\\bin\\mysqld.exe";

try
{
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
} 
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into Runtime.exec(), which will allow you to start mySQL via console.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html

Comment: 1) I would recommend the use of a `ProcessBuilder` instead of `Runtime.exec()` 2) Try to link to more up-to-date documentation in an answer.  Right now, you are linking to Java 1.5

Comment: Fair enough.  It's just the Java Doc link that came up first in Google, still works the same in 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

```
Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = runTime.exec(String[] cmdarray, String[] envp, File dir);
p.waitFor();
```

Answer (score -3):

Easiest way is to use [JDBC](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html) all you need to do then is send queries to the server and interpret the results. A simple way to connect is below.

```
import java.sql.*;
Connection conn;
private void connect()
{
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://serverURL","user","pass);
        System.out.println("Connection Established");
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        System.err.println("Unable to load the MySQL driver.");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: This expects the server to be running. He needs to start it.