# Start mysql server from java

Tags: java, mysql

How to start and stop mysql server from java(OSX) programtically?Can someone provide a code snippet for this.
Non of the code snippets given in stackoverflow are working properly.

Comment: Have you looked at this post?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237860/connect-java-to-mysql-using-jdbc-on-osx

Comment: I have seen these posts  1)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16181993/how-to-start-a-mysql-server-in-java-programatically  2)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22062568/start-and-stop-mysql-through-java

Comment: @keews Isn't the link u given is about connecting to a database after starting a server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry, I can't comment because I do not have enough reputation.

What you could try is running the start script from the command line. That means getting the runtime and setting the command tou need. i.e,

```
Runtime.getRuntime.exec("sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start");
```

Another possibility would be to create a ProccesBuilder and set the params you need for the startup.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just a small correction. Runtime.getRuntime().exec().Brackets missing.Yes it is working.but then I have to destroy the process to stop the server."server.mysql.server stop" is not working when I am using it in java.